# Property name expected type of string but got undefined

Tags: json, typescript, antlr, antlr4

My .babelrc.json file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
    ["@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose" : true }],
    "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose" : true }],
        "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator"
      ],
      "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }],
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  projects: [
    {
      displayName: 'node',
      rootDir: __dirname,
      testEnvironment: 'node',
      testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '.browser.js', 'dist'],
      transform: {
        '^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$': './babel-jest-transformer.js',
      },
      transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/yaml$'],
      globals: {
        __NODE__: true,
        __BROWSER__: false,
        __DEV__: true,
      },
    },
    {
      displayName: 'browser',
      rootDir: __dirname,
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '.node.js', 'dist'],
      transform: {
        '^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$': './babel-jest-transformer.js',
      },
      transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/yaml$'],
      globals: {
        __NODE__: false,
        __BROWSER__: true,
        __DEV__: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['cobertura', 'html'],
};
```

My devDependencies:

```
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators": "7.19.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.20.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.18.6",
    "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator": "1.0.16",
```

When I run `jz test`, I got the following:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: /Users/proj/src/libts/antlr4ts/atn/SemanticContext.ts: Property name expected type of string but got undefined

      at validate (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-types-npm-7.20.5-6bde64109f-773f0a1ad9.zip/node_modules/@babel/types/src/definitions/utils.ts:182:13)
      at Object.fn [as validate] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-types-npm-7.20.5-6bde64109f-773f0a1ad9.zip/node_modules/@babel/types/src/definitions/utils.ts:252:7)
      at validate (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-types-npm-7.20.5-6bde64109f-773f0a1ad9.zip/node_modules/@babel/types/src/validators/validate.ts:32:9)
      at validateField (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-types-npm-7.20.5-6bde64109f-773f0a1ad9.zip/node_modules/@babel/types/src/validators/validate.ts:19:3)
      at validateNode (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-types-npm-7.20.5-6bde64109f-773f0a1ad9.zip/node_modules/@babel/types/src/builders/validateNode.ts:9:13)
      at Object.identifier (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-types-npm-7.20.5-6bde64109f-773f0a1ad9.zip/node_modules/@babel/types/src/builders/generated/index.ts:244:22)
      at ../../../../../../.yarn/cache/babel-plugin-parameter-decorator-npm-1.0.16-d82c52e96f-5a0d8ce40b.zip/node_modules/babel-plugin-parameter-decorator/lib/index.js:23:82
      at ../../../../../../.yarn/cache/babel-plugin-parameter-decorator-npm-1.0.16-d82c52e96f-5a0d8ce40b.zip/node_modules/babel-plugin-parameter-decorator/lib/index.js:222:85
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ../../../../../../.yarn/cache/babel-plugin-parameter-decorator-npm-1.0.16-d82c52e96f-5a0d8ce40b.zip/node_modules/babel-plugin-parameter-decorator/lib/index.js:204:30
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at PluginPass.Function (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/babel-plugin-parameter-decorator-npm-1.0.16-d82c52e96f-5a0d8ce40b.zip/node_modules/babel-plugin-parameter-decorator/lib/index.js:201:44)
      at call (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/visitors.ts:250:21)
      at NodePath.call [as _call] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/path/context.ts:34:20)
      at NodePath._call [as call] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/path/context.ts:19:17)
      at NodePath.call [as visit] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/path/context.ts:92:31)
      at TraversalContext.visit [as visitQueue] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:144:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue [as visitMultiple] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:98:17)
      at TraversalContext.visitMultiple [as visit] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:174:19)
      at visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/traverse-node.ts:34:17)
      at NodePath.visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/path/context.ts:99:33)
      at TraversalContext.visit [as visitQueue] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:144:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue [as visitSingle] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:108:19)
      at TraversalContext.visitSingle [as visit] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:176:19)
      at visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/traverse-node.ts:34:17)
      at NodePath.visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/path/context.ts:99:33)
      at TraversalContext.visit [as visitQueue] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:144:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue [as visitSingle] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:108:19)
      at TraversalContext.visitSingle [as visit] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:176:19)
      at visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/traverse-node.ts:34:17)
      at NodePath.visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/path/context.ts:99:33)
      at TraversalContext.visit [as visitQueue] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:144:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue [as visitMultiple] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:98:17)
      at TraversalContext.visitMultiple [as visit] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:174:19)
      at visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/traverse-node.ts:34:17)
      at NodePath.visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/path/context.ts:99:33)
      at TraversalContext.visit [as visitQueue] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:144:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:150:21)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue [as visitSingle] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:108:19)
      at TraversalContext.visitSingle [as visit] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:176:19)
      at visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/traverse-node.ts:34:17)
      at NodePath.visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/path/context.ts:99:33)
      at TraversalContext.visit [as visitQueue] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:144:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue [as visitMultiple] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:98:17)
      at TraversalContext.visitMultiple [as visit] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:174:19)
      at visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/traverse-node.ts:34:17)
      at NodePath.visit (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/path/context.ts:99:33)
      at TraversalContext.visit [as visitQueue] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:144:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:150:21)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue [as visitSingle] (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/@babel-traverse-npm-7.20.5-2965e66783-c7fed46861.zip/node_modules/@babel/traverse/src/context.ts:108:19)
```

Any idea why? Is there anything wrong with my `.babelrc.json` file? Thank you. How can I find the line which raised the error?

By the way, I copied antlr4ts/src into my project to avoid circle import issue. I am using jazelle, and [Yarn PNP](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp)

Comment: having the same issue, did you find out what was wrong in jest ?